# Scrapy: How to make a conditional (present or absent) XPATH return values when absent?

Tags: python, xpath, conditional-statements, selector, scrapy

I am seeking to scrape particular product information from a website. One of my desired XPATH criteria, however, does not appear on every product's page. (While all products have name, price, etc, some do not have the recommended age displayed).

This is not a problem, however, when scrapy writes or even returns the data in the shell, it is no longer in the order associated with the start-url's list, nor does it respect the absence of data from some of the urls. Hence, all of my data (multiple columns of different variables) does not match the new age column since it is much shorter and out of order. This is not the case when I focus only on products that do have the age displayed.

Is there a way to make pages without the desired XPATH and age return a blank space to maintain matched column order in my data?

Here is my XPATH selector:

```
item["age"] = hxs.select('//li[contains(@class,"our-age")]/span/text()').extract()
```

(Some webpages do not have the age and thus lack completely the  path.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xpath = '//li[contains(@class,"our-age")]/span/text()'
item["age"] = hxs.select(xpath).extract() or [' ']
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it for the most part. Parsing order is still off (I'm scraping two levels of the website with two separate spiders and need their results to match row-by-row).